# Getting error Cannot find module 'cryptile' while installing express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am new to node js and facing issue in installing express js. Please help in fixing the issue and install express js.

[image]

Now when i tried to install cryptiles module using the command "npm install cryptiles" i am getting the same error.

[image]

Comment: Looks like your NPM installation is broken. Try reinstalling Node and NPM.

Answer (score -1):

Just run `npm install cryptiles` then re-run your previous command

or if you don't want then go to your packages.json file and remove the dependency...

**UPDATE :**

**Seems this package isn't supported anymore** ..
To see yourself install globally:

```
npm install -g cryptiles
```

then install try to install in source destination

```
npm install cryptiles
```

**You should get the following message:**

```
npm WARN install Couldn't install optional dependency: Unsupported
```